# Bootstrap 3 Collapse Menu stopped working in IOS7

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, ios7, twitter-bootstrap-3

After IOS7 upgrade navigated to my site with in Iphone and Ipad and the collapse menu button on bootstrap 3 menu stopped working. Brand link in menu still work but button to show submenu does not. Functions normal in Chrome, IE, Firefox, and desktop version of safari.

Link to test site
[enter link description here](https://www.pluscu.org/redesign2/index.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out... you have to use a `<button>` tag for the collapse button and NOT an `<A>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

See http://mashable.com/2013/09/20/apple-fixing-multiple-ios-7-bugs-already/

Given that your menu functions normally in a diverse set of browsers, this is most probably an IOS7 bug, of which there are reportedly many, some of them fairly serious.

7.01 is due out today which includes a large number of bug fixes..  Perhaps this bug is fixed.  I generally consider it unwise to update to the initial major version upgrade of an OS, especially when the OS release has been as hyped as this one was.

Answer (score 0):

I found it easier to just add class='btn' to whatever element had data-toggle="collapse". It work beautifully.